# Making a phone call and get duration afterward in Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Forms or Android developers,

I'm writing an app in Xamarin Forms that has the ability to make a call from a phonebook that's separate from the systems phonebook. The key question is how I get the ability to log the duration of the phone call afterward.

I couldn't find a NuGet package that did this. So I started to Google for Android native solutions. I also need to get this to work on iOS, but for now I'm focusing on Android. The first thing I did was trying to get the state of the phone. What I found was that you could get the phone states: ringing, idle and offhook. But none of them tell the actual duration of the call. The next thing I found was that I could query the call duration from the call logs. This worked. What I'm currently doing is listening for the call to go from offhook to idle. When this happens I query the CallLog for the last call duration using the time the call button was clicked and using the phone number from the phonebook. This works in principle but I think I'm missing something. Am I doing this the right way? Is this the only way to do this?

Kind Regards,

Wim

Answer (score 0):

> What I found was that you could get the phone states: ringing, idle
> and offhook. But none of them tell the actual duration of the call.

You can use `BroadcastReceiver` to listen to the phone states and calculate the result.

Please refer to the following code:

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true)] 
    [IntentFilter(new[] { "android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"})]  
    public class CallDurationReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {

        double start_time,end_time;
        public override void OnReceive(Context? context, Intent? intent)
        {
            if (intent == null) { return; }

            var stateStr = intent.GetStringExtra(TelephonyManager.ExtraState);

            if (stateStr != null && stateStr.Equals(TelephonyManager.ExtraStateRinging)) {

                start_time = GetCurrentMilli();
            }

            if (stateStr != null && stateStr.Equals(TelephonyManager.ExtraStateIdle)) {

                end_time = GetCurrentMilli();

                //total time talked is:
                double total_time = end_time-start_time;

            }
        }

        public static double GetCurrentMilli()
        {

            DateTime Jan1970 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

            TimeSpan javaSpan = DateTime.UtcNow - Jan1970;

            return javaSpan.TotalMilliseconds;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello Jessie, thank you for your answer. Your solution works perfectly for incoming calls. But the problem I have is logging the duration on an outgoing call. I've used the built-in Dialer and Xam.Plugins.Messaging. Both don't have an option to do this. At this moment I'm using the package because it can make the directly without the 'about-to-make-a-call' screen where you can still cancel the call.

Comment: `At this moment I'm using the package because it can make the directly without the 'about-to-make-a-call' screen where you can still cancel the call.`  What's the `package ` ? Have you resolved this problem?

Comment: With 'the package' I mean Xam.Plugins.Messaging. I have resolved it but it seems kind of hacky to me. I am wondering if there is a better solution to this problem. I found the same solution as the one I came up with on another stackoverflow page. But it was the OP who marked his own question as answered with no other answers on the page. And he used timers to wait for the log to register the call. I don't think it's elegant and I think there must be a better solution to this.